# How to get order tax details and rates in WooCommerce?

Tags: php, wordpress, woocommerce, orders, tax

I'm trying to get the **tax percentage** for a custom variable in a plugin from an order. Of course I could request a lot of data via `$order-> get_ ...`, but I cannot find a method to get the tax percentage (like for example '21' -> 21%).

Anyone have an idea to make this simple?

Answer (score 13):

You will have **to get order tax item(s)** which will give you an array of [`WC_Order_Item_Tax`](https://docs.woocommerce.com/wc-apidocs/class-WC_Order_Item_Tax.html) Objects which protected properties are accessible using [`WC_Order_Item_Tax` available methods](https://docs.woocommerce.com/wc-apidocs/class-WC_Order_Item_Tax.html) like:

```
// Get the the WC_Order Object from an order ID (optional)
$order = wc_get_order( $order_id );

foreach($order->get_items('tax') as $item_id => $item ) {
    $tax_rate_id    = $item->get_rate_id(); // Tax rate ID
    $tax_rate_code  = $item->get_rate_code(); // Tax code
    $tax_label      = $item->get_label(); // Tax label name
    $tax_name       = $item->get_name(); // Tax name
    $tax_total      = $item->get_tax_total(); // Tax Total
    $tax_ship_total = $item->get_shipping_tax_total(); // Tax shipping total
    $tax_compound   = $item->get_compound(); // Tax compound
    $tax_percent    = WC_Tax::get_rate_percent( $tax_rate_id ); // Tax percentage
    $tax_rate       = str_replace('%', '', $tax_percent); // Tax rate


    echo '<p>Rate id: '. $tax_rate_id . '<br>'; // Tax rate ID
    echo 'Rate code: '. $tax_rate_code . '<br>'; // Tax code
    echo 'Tax label: '. $tax_label . '<br>'; // Tax label name
    echo 'Tax name: '. $tax_name . '<br>'; // Tax name
    echo 'Tax Total: '. $tax_total . '<br>'; // Tax Total
    echo 'Tax shipping total: '. $tax_ship_total . '<br>'; // Tax shipping total
    echo 'Tax compound: '. $tax_compound . '<br>'; // Tax shipping total
    echo 'Tax percentage: '. $tax_percent . '<br>'; // Tax shipping total
    echo 'Tax rate: '. $tax_rate . '</p>'; // Tax percentage
}
```

Tested and works

You can also use some [`WC_Tax` available methods](https://docs.woocommerce.com/wc-apidocs/class-WC_Tax.html) like in the code

> Note that you can have **many 'tax" items with different tax rates** in an order. Shipping can have its own tax rate too. Same thing for fees, as you can set a tax class. Also remember that taxes rates are based on customer location.

---

Finally you can also use some [`WC_Abstract_Order` methods](https://docs.woocommerce.com/wc-apidocs/class-WC_Abstract_Order.html#methods) to get taxes amounts details like:

```
// Get the the WC_Order Object from an order ID (optional)
$order = wc_get_order( $order_id );

$discount_tax         = $order->get_discount_tax();
$shipping_tax_total   = $order->get_shipping_tax();
$order_total_tax      = $order->get_total_tax();
$cart_total_tax       = $order->get_cart_tax();
$formatted_tax_totals = $order->get_tax_totals();
```